# How do I print the last 5 fields in awk?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, awk

I have 10 fields and I want to start from field 5 to field 10 and ignore the first 5 fields. How can I use NF in awk to do that?

```
f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

I want to show only:

```
f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446255/how-to-remove-the-first-two-columns-in-a-file-using-shell-awk-sed-whatever, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400819/remove-first-columns-then-leave-remaining-line-untouched-in-awk

Comment: You ask for `awk`, so `cut -f6- file` for fixed 10 fields, or counting from the end with `rev file | cut -f1-5 | rev` may work but don't count as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to loop through the fields:

```
bash-4.3$ awk '{for(i=6;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" "; print ""}' input_file.txt 
f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 
c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

Or you can make fields equal to Null string:

```
bash-4.3$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=5;i++) $i="";print}' input_file.txt 
     f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
     c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

Or use substring of the whole line , to print all characters from where field 6 begins (credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900372/3701431):

```
bash-4.3$ awk '{print substr($0,index($0,$6))}' input_file.txt 
f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

or simply use `cut` command:

```
bash-4.3$ cut -d " " -f6-10  input_file.txt 
f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

Python can do that too:

```
bash-4.3$ python -c 'import sys;fields=[" ".join(line.strip().split()[5:]) for line in sys.stdin];print "\n".join(fields)' < input_file.txt 
f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

or alternatively:

```
$ python -c "import sys;print '\n'.join(map(lambda x:' '.join(x.split()[5:]),sys.stdin.readlines()))" < input_file.txt
f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

Or with Ruby:

```
bash-4.3$ ruby -ne 'print $_.split()[5..10].join(" ");print "\n"' < input_file.txt 
f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

Bash + xargs can do it too, although a bit more convoluted:

```
bash-4.3$ cat input_file.txt | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'arr=($@);for i in $(seq 5 10);do printf "%s " ${arr[$i]} ; done; echo' sh
f6 f7 f8 f9 f10  
c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

Comment: I don't think the solution with index() will work if some of the other fields may be equal to or contain $6.

Comment: yes, this will work only in this specific case

Comment: `printf $i" "` will fail when the field has a `%`.

Answer (score 5):

Just process the fields of interest.  That will be the last field -4, the last field -3, until the actual last field.

Reading from a file with this content (**file.txt**):

```
f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

Run awk on the file as described below.  The line with the `$` sign is the command.  The last two lines are the output.

```bash
$ awk '{print $(NF-4)" "$(NF-3)" "$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF}' file.txt
f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

**Note**:  As pointed out by Cyrus in the comment, I removed the bash script and left just the print statement to make it simpler and faster.

Comment: or `awk '{print $(NF-4)" "$(NF-3)" "$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF}' file.txt`

Comment: Thanks !  I'll add the shorter version to the answer.  Leaving out the cat pipe.